# How to run a script at logon in Windows 10 Bash shell?

Tags: windows-10, bash

How can I run a Bash script (such as https://github.com/willemdh/firemotd) when I open the Bash shell for Windows 10?

I tried putting a script in /etc/profile.d but it doesn't seem to get executed. Also tried executing the script from .profile in the main user home folder, but this also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: are you running bash on windows startup?

Comment: I start as admin in Cmder with "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of bash use ~/.bash_profile

1. open bash shell
2. vim ~/.bash_profile
3. source ~/.bash_profile or exit shell then open shell